# Adding element to list crashes program...sometimes

Tags: c++, list, pointers, crash

I'm working on a GUI project and for some reason the following call add_gfx_object() crashes my program.

```
MainMenuState::MainMenuState(Demo& demo)
    : m_start_button{new Button(Sol::Rectangle{Sol::Vector{10, 10}, 100, 30}, 
      [] {std::cout << "clicked";})}
{
    demo.add_gfx_object(m_start_button); // <-- crashes program
}
```

---

The relevent code in the Demo class is listed here.

```
class Demo : public Sol::Application
{
public:
    StateMachine<Demo> fsm;

    Demo();
    ~Demo();

    //...

    void add_gfx_object(const GraphicalEntity* const obj) {m_draw_list.push_back(obj);}

private:
    std::list<const GraphicalEntity*> m_draw_list;

    void draw_objects();
};
```

---

Strangely enough, this call to add_gfx_object() does not crash my program.

```
Demo::Demo()
    : Application("Demo", 800, 600, false), fsm(*this, new MainMenuState(*this))
{
    add_gfx_object(new Button(Sol::Rectangle(), []{})); // <-- does not crash program
}
```

Replacing the Button pointers with nullptr in these examples yields the same results. As much as I would like to provide additional information on the issue, I am unable to. Can anyone shed some insight onto why my program keeps crashing?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux How so? Replacing the Button pointer with nullptr yields the same result in both cases.

Comment: Beware of raw owning pointers. For example, the use of raw owning pointers is causing `MainMenuState::MainMenuState(Demo& demo)` to not be exception safe. You also need to keep the [rule of 0/3/5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) in mind at all time if you choose to use them.

Comment: I misunderstood the part where you mention `nullptr`. I've retracted my first comment. But the point stands that the problem likely lies outside of the provided code. Consider preparing a [MCVE].

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The MainMenuState class does take care of copy assignment and construction. By not exception safe are you referring to std::bad_alloc?

Comment: I'm referring to the fact that stack unwinding doesn't (can't) automatically `delete` objects owned by raw pointers. It's not immediately obvious that no part of the constructor can throw, meaning you can potentially leak which violates even the basic exception guarantee. Perhaps the constructor can't possibly throw, but that can't be assumed from the snippet. Even if it can't the, design practices shown indicate that the situation is likely wide spread. If this is a concern for you, using smart pointers avoids these issues and many many other.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the order in with you created the objects.

You call the constructor of the base class (`Application`) of `Demo` in the constructor list of `Demo` and the constructor of the member `fsm`. During the construction of `Demo`, the base class is constructed first, and only after that the other members of `Demo` are constructed in the order they are declared -first `fsm` and only afteer that the list `m_draw_list`.

But to the constructor of `fsm` you try to pass a pointer result of a call to the constructor of `MainMenuState` passing to the last `*this` with is a partially constructed `Demo` object with no list yet. So in this call to `MainMenuState(Demo& demo)` what crash your program is the intent to use an uninitialized list.

You have to think about how to organize your code and prevent circular dependences of object creation. You may need to pass some of the parameters to already fully created objects, for example inside the body of the constructor, where all members are already constructed, including the list, like in the example that "works". In this case, alternatively you could declare the private list  `m_draw_list` before the public `fsm`.